# PHP - file uploads and ways to prevent viruses from being uploaded in zip/rar archives

Tags: php, mysql, web

I am trying to provide a service on my website to allow users to upload files so others can download them.

The issue is, since some of these files I will allow to upload will be .zip/.rar files, I am curious as to what ideas exist to help prevent the uploading of archives with Viruses/trojans etc. included. Some .zip files will include legitimate .exe files,though I am not sure what options I have.

I thought about it and I don't have a method for verifying with a virus scanner on the server, since I am on shared hosting w/o the option to run a service like that... nor do I have the knowledge on how to do that. I am also aware there is no php class or database to scan the files for viruses. This means, my only options are to rely on:

a). manual approval <-- not an acceptable option for me as it might become a busy site with thousands of uploads
b). get the users to somehow point out it if has viruses through voting or "flagging", etc....

anyway, regarding "b" - what ideas would you suggest?

Comment: Are you sure your shared hosting provider allows file upload hosting on your service? Most of them don't, and that's one of the main reasons why they don't.

Comment: In some countries you are liable for anything downloaded from your site, Don't do it, unless you know exactly what is being uploaded/downloaded.

Comment: The files are "mods" for a game. the files could be .exe or they could be something simple like image files to mod the game... couldn't I simply add in my Terms and Conditions section that by using this website you, the user agree that I cannot be held liable for what is up/downloaded as not all files can be verified etc. etc.

Comment: No - you can't change laws in another country by putting a disclaimer on your website. If you need to publish content which can potentially contain embedded malware then there is **nothing** you can do to prevent the facility from being abused (even scanning every file with every virus checker gives no guarantees - go read the warranty on your AV software of choice). Even if you're only allowing static content which you know is clean (e.g. by format cycling) then you've got virtually no protection against intellectual property claims.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Report" button sounds like a good idea, maybe you could add a comment system too to allow people to explain why they think the file is a virus or simply a useless file (and find a way to "give thanks" to the user, like the reputation system on StackOverflow ?).

Comment: I have a comments system in place already. I also already added the flagging system too. I am wondering about other additional ideas, if any... the only other thing I just thought of is to manually approve them - only I can have "trusted" users who I automatically approve. This way I only need to check an upload from a user the first time, after that I "trust" they won't do anything bad... and then I also provide the other features: flagging and comments.

Comment: And give the "trusted" users the ability to mark a file as "dangerous" as proposed by Robus ?

Answer (score 0):

A big "report virus" button next to download? Manually approving these should be possible.

Or mark the file as "Potentially dangerous" after a number of clicks.